# Java: Netty and multithreaded Invoker (Command Pattern)

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, command-pattern

I am currently developing a server using [Netty](http://netty.io) and the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). During the implementation of the invoker, I got the idea to implement it using several threads in order to ensure high command execution performance.

However, I started wondering whether this is necessary with Netty, as Netty creates multiple threads on it's own. So now my question: Is the invoker already multi-threaded, if I pass a thread safe invoker object to the Netty handlers and call the invoke()-method from there? If that's the case, is this good practice or should I rather create my own invoker threads?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found the answer to my questions. I'll post it here, if anyone comes across a similar question:

> Is the invoker already multi-threaded, if I pass a thread safe invoker object to the Netty handlers and call the invoke()-method from there?

Yes, unless otherwise specified, the Netty handlers will built up `2 * count of cores` threads. The channel handlers are thereby often executed in different threads, so a simple invocation of the command.execute() method will already be multi-threaded due to the nature of netty.

> Is this good practice?

Yes, otherwise too many threads are created and the tasks for the netty worker threads will just be delegated unnecessarily.